# How can i fix tbb on CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, tbb

I have this problem.

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package):   By not providing
>   "FindTBB.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has   asked CMake to
>   find a package configuration file provided by "TBB", but   CMake did
>   not find one.

I could not find a package configuration file provided by "TBB" with any of the following names:

```
TBBConfig.cmake
tbb-config.cmake
```

> Add the installation prefix of "TBB" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
>   "TBB_DIR"   to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
>   "TBB" provides a   separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
>   been installed.

how can i fix this?

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(deneme)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include("C:/yunus/Git/inteltbb/tbb/cmake/TBBBuild.cmake")

tbb_build(TBB_ROOT "C:/yunus/Git/inteltbb/tbb" CONFIG_DIR TBB_DIR)
find_package(TBB REQUIRED tbb)

add_executable(deneme main.cpp ToDo.cpp ToDo.h)
```

Comment: Doesn't the last paragraph of the error message tell you exactly what to do?

Answer (score 4):

`TBB` does not come by default with a `FindTBB.cmake` module so the guidelines in the error message are a bit misleading.

If your project provides the corresponding `FindTBB.cmake` module you need to add the path to it and the path to the `TBB` installation to your `CMake` call, i.e.

```
cmake . -G "<your generator here>" -DTBB_DIR=<path to TBB installation> -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=<path to FindTBB.cmake>
```

Otherwise you need to download a suitable `FindTBB.cmake` module e.g. https://github.com/schuhschuh/cmake-basis-modules/blob/develop/FindTBB.cmake

This one uses TBB_ROOT instead of TBB_DIR.

***Edit:***

Try the binary package integration of TBB first.
Comment the `include(...)` and the `tbb_build(...)` command and add

```
target_link_libraries(deneme ${TBB_IMPORTED_TARGETS})
```

to your `CMakeLists.txt` after the `add_executable` call. Then call

```
cmake . -G "<your generator here>" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=<path to your TBB installation>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But when i tried this it says "Intel TBB can not be built: required make-tool (gmake) was not found". how can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you post your CMakeLists.txt and give some additional information what kind of project you are building? That would help much.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean here `"<your generator here>"`

Comment: @bhordupur As the OP did not specify what CMake generator should be used I inserted a placeholder. See `cmake --help` on your platform for a list of supported generators.